# Nested method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is this code

```
def out
  def in
    puts "in"
  end
  puts "out"
end
```

the exact same as:

```
def out
  puts "out"
end

def in
  puts "in"
end
```

except in first case I can use "out.in" to call.
is there any other difference worth noticing?

Comment: The first is less common, and requires more thought.

Comment: Note that you if you want a 'helper' function inside a method, you can create a lambda in the method and then invoke that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In Ruby, global methods are methods defined on `Object`, the class from which all classes inherit. When you say this:

```
def a
  def b
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

you are declaring two separate methods on `Object`, `a` and `b`. The only reason you can call `b` as `a.b` is because `a` returns `nil`, which is an object of `NilClass`, which is a child of `Object`.

**Edit:** As @steenslag noticed in the comments, the methods are actually defined as *private* instance methods on Object, so you can only call them from within the scope of an `Object`, not as, say `5.a`.

The only difference worth noticing, as Dave Newton mentioned in the comments, is that the first is confusing and subtle, and looks like someone from Python is learning Ruby, and doesn't yet understand how methods are handled.

**Note:** The reason that top-level methods are defined as methods on `Object` is that the `def` keyword, unless specified otherwise, defines a method on the class of whatever `self` is right now. Anywhere in the top level and top level methods, `self` is the special object `main`, which happens to be an `Object`.

Comment: `5.a # => NoMethodError: private method 'a' called for 5:Fixnum
`

Comment: @meizin: also note that each `a.b` call will redefine `b`. To see turn warnings  on (`$VERBOSE = true` or `ruby -w` ).

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `in` is a terrible name for a method, since it conflicts with the `in` keyword.

> is there any other difference worth noticing?

Yes, they are *completely* different. In the first case, there is a method `out` which, when called, will (re-)define a method `in`. In the second case, there are two methods `out` and `in`.

This means that in the second case, it doesn't matter what order you call the methods in. But in the first case, if you call `in` before you call `out`, you get a `NoMethodError`, because `in` is defined by calling `out`. Also, if you call `out` multiple times, you will get a method redefinition warning everytime but the first:

```
def outer
  def inner; 'inner' end
  'outer'
end

inner
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `inner' for main:Object

inner()
# NoMethodError: undefined method `inner' for main:Object

outer
# => 'outer'

inner
# => 'inner'

outer
# :2: warning: method redefined; discarding old inner
# :2: warning: previous definition of inner was here
# => 'outer'
```